# Turning off layer visibility in ArcGIS Pro with Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, visibility

I have code that exports several maps. For a set of maps, I want to make sure one layer used in a previous map is turned off. I don't want to remove it completely.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]  
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]

for elm in lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT", "Layer"):
        elm.visible = False
```

Comment: What does happen when you run it?  No layers or all layers turn off?  Nothing at all?  Errors, or something else?

Comment: @Midavlo Nothing at all. It finishes but the layer does not turn off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that your `for` loop never runs, because there is no layout element that matches your `"Layer"` wildcard.

You should be getting your layers from the map, not from the layout.  Use `m.listLayers("wildcard")` for this.

Eg,

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]  
layer = m.listLayers("my_layer_name")[0]
layer.visible = False
```